# Operator to convert Observable<List<Object>> to Object

Tags: android, rx-java2

Any Help Appreciated !!! First time when user come to screen it check the data is available in local storage or not , if not then ,it request the data from the network and then dump into the local storage ,if data available in local Storage then it's show data from the local storage.
My problem here is that i am getting the response from the server in the form of list while making network call and i want to insert the data to the local storage which is expecting object from the network result . How i can achieve this part . My try

```
@Override
    public void getEventDetail(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        Single<List<EventDetailResponse>> getAllEventFromLocalDb = getDataManager().getAllEventDetail();
        Single<List<EventDetailResponse>> getEventFromNetwork = getDataManager().doEventDetailCall(jsonObject);
        Flowable<List<EventDetailResponse>> response = Single.concat(getAllEventFromLocalDb, getEventFromNetwork);
        getCompositeDisposable().add(response
                .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty()).first(new ArrayList<>())
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe(list->{
                    Log.e("sizee",""+list.size());
                },throwable -> {handleError(throwable);}));
    }
```

I am getting the list size perfectly while fetching the data from the network. Below observable i have to call above and get the result once in onsubscribe.

```
public Observable<Long> insertEventDetail(EventDetailResponse eventDetailResponse) {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long call() throws Exception {
                return mDaoSession.getEventDetailResponseDao().insert(eventDetailResponse);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `flatMapIterable` to iterate every item in your list. Remember `flatMapIterable` doesn't respect the original order in your list. If the order needs to be preserved, use `concatMapIterable`:

```
getCompositeDisposable().add(response
            .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
            .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
            .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
            .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
            .subscribe(item -> {
                insertEventDetail(item);
                Log.e("sizee",""+list.size());
            },throwable -> {handleError(throwable);}));
```

Comment: i need all the object in the list , currently u r fetching only one object from the list

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Check the edited answer